# How big is the center of an orthogonal group?

Tags: lie-groups, gr.group-theory

How big is the center of an arbitrary orthogonal group $O(m,n)$?

In the special case of the "circle group" $O(2)$, it's clear that $|\zeta O(2)|$ = 1. In the case of $O(3)$, it seems clear that the center has two elements $\zeta O(3) = \lbrace 1, -1 \rbrace$. I can see this by visualizing a sphere in an arbitrary $(i, j, k)$ basis, and observing that both the identity and the "complete" reversal $(i, j, k) \mapsto (-i, -j, -k)$ commute with everthing.

But I'd like a simple way to see how the situation changes for more general orthogonal groups like the (inhomogeneous) Lorentz group $O(3,1)$.

Comment: You don't mean what you said about the circle group. Where an orthogonal group acts irreducibly (over the complex numbers) on a vector space, its only central elements must act as scalars.

Comment: Thanks -- I was thinking about $O$ over the real number field, for which what I said is correct. But as you suggest, the question gets more interesting for $O$ over arbitrary fields!

Comment: The centre of $O(m,n)$ for $m+n\ge1$ always as exactly
two elements: $I$ and $-I$.

Comment: I'm maybe utterly pedantic, however let's say that the center is trivial in char 2, since $I$ and $-I$ coincide.

Comment: Robin -- could you elaborate? I seem to recall from somewhere that the Lorentz group has a 4-element center...

Comment: What could possibly be in the centre of O(3,1) save for $I$ and $-I$%?
Perhaps you're thinking that diag(1,1,1,-1) is central? It isn't.

Comment: Francesco, you're not being utterly pedantic. You could go further: In characteristic $2$ the group $O(2)$ is commutative and does not consist entirely of scalar matrices. 

Comment: Soulphysics -- You are confusing the centre with the group of components. $O(n)$ has two connected components, $O(3,1)$ has four.

Comment: Thanks Robin -- I've convinced myself now. Although the Lorentz group has four interesting discrete transformations, only I and -I are central.

Comment: Francesco, Tom: in char 2, you use bad notion of center; e.g., ${\rm{SL}}_p$ has scheme-theoretic $\mu_p \ne 1$ in char. $p > 0$.  If $(V,q)$ is a non-deg. quad. space of dim $n \ge 3$ then ${\rm{SO}}(q) := {\rm{O}}(q) \cap {\rm{SL}}(V)$ is smooth (so has good notion of scheme-theoretic center) and its scheme-th. center is the "scalar" $\mu_2$ when $n$ is even and trivial when $n$ is odd.  Also, ${\rm{O}}(q) = {\rm{SO}}(q)$ when $n$ even and ${\rm{O}}(q) = {\rm{SO}}(q) \times \mu_2$ when $n$ odd. So for char. 2 & $n > 2$, one should say ${\rm{O}}(q)$ has scheme-th. center $\mu_2$ ($ \ne 1$).

Comment: Voting to close as "no longer relevant".

Comment: BCnrd: I was also (knowingly) using a bad notion of $O(2)$, or really two of them: either the symmetries of the bilinear form given by the identity matrix or the symmetries of the (degenerate) quad form $(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)^2$. 

Comment: I'm reluctant to add yet another comment, but the original question was too imprecisely formulated to have a clear answer.   The structure of classical groups depends heavily on the underlying field, apparently meant to be the real field here; but also the notation used gets somewhat out of control from a mathematical viewpoint.  There is definitely a communication barrier between mathematics and physics even in the most classical areas. 